# Bring the temperature of the site openweathermap

Tags: android

I have problem in website openweathermap
I want to bring the temperature
my city now 30

```
{"coord":{"lon":114.1,"lat":22.37},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.15,"pressure":1008,"humidity":89,"temp_min":302.15,"temp_max":302.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.1,"deg":210},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1497443400,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7904,"message":0.0041,"country":"HK","sunrise":1497389947,"sunset":1497438532},"id":1818209,"name":"Tsuen Wan","cod":200}
```

but i can't found number 30
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your json, inside main there is "temp": 302.15 ...
It looks like the temperature is retrived in Kelvin and not in Celsius.
Following this link https://openweathermap.org/forecast16#data you should be able to see that you have to change your API request in something like:

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=YOURCITYHERE&units=metric

Comment: Can I bring the time now in the city as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "bring the time"? try to be a bit more specific

Comment: for example how much time in China now

Comment: at this link https://openweathermap.org/api you can find all the info that you need. You can make API call about the current weather (like now) using the link in the previous answer, if you need the weather for the next 5 days you have to use api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=YOURCITYHERE&units=metric